# Override UIManager value for single object

Tags: java, swing, background, jlabel, uimanager

Is it possible to override the `UIManager` properties for specific objects?

For example, my UI Manager has

```
[Label.background] => (ColorUIResource) [javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=238,g=238,b=238]]
```

I want to make ONE `JLabel` with a `Color.WHITE` background.

```
whiteJLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE)
```

..has no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
whiteJLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE)
whiteJLabel.setOpaque(true);
```